# Max possible discipline boost from equipment

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-demon-hunter

Demon hunter cloak and quiver can have "Max Discipline" attribute,  but there are several other slots with legendary items that can have it such as [Stone of Jordan](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/stone-of-jordan).

I'm looking for which combination of items (including legendary) will result in the highest amount of Discipline.

Comment: somewhat related, the 4 set bonus for Natalya's with +2 discipline regeneration is hugely overpowered, which is one reason why Natalya's rings sell for 70m :(

Comment: @yx. "overpowered" is an opinion, I agree that it is powerful.  I do not play DH much, but I think it would be cool to have the 4-set because it would open up alternative skill builds if you had enough +discipline

Comment: @DiabloMonkey with the +2 regen, its possible for a DH to stay invisible/invincible for 30 seconds at a time, I'd consider that overpowered :P  And DH is my main character too.

Comment: @yx. personally, I still don't consider 30s at a time overpowered because without invincibility, from what I have gathered, most DHs usually squish.  They are reliant upon damage avoidance (dodge, kiting, SS, and kiting) rather than damage reduction like most classes.  While possible... you don't see many DHs stacking all resist with the goal of surviving 4-6 attacks instead of just being able to survive 1. Nat's 4-set bonus is not required, but opens new doors.

Comment: @DiabloMonkey trust me, 30 seconds is an absurdly long time to be invincible, it'll allow me to walk 99% of inferno with ease.  One of the first skill nerfs bliz did was to lower lingering fog duration from 2 seconds to 1.5.  Like I said there's a reason why natalaya's is so expensive right now, because that regen is so powerful.

Comment: @yx. You mean cutting SS from 2s to 1s; and Lingering Fog used to be +1s (now +0.5s)

Answer (score 4):

Let us assume max discipline value of all items:

Belt - Hellcat Waistguard [Legacy] +8 Discipline

Ring - Stone of Jordan [Legacy] (Will only count once since it's unique equipped, meaning we can't equip two of them; can equip the Legacy version with the non-Legacy version) +8 Discipline

Ring - Stone of Jordan (Will only count once since it's unique equipped, meaning we can't equip two of them) +10 Discipline

Gloves - Frostburn Gauntlets +4 Discipline

Amulet - Xephirian Amulet +10 Discipline

Cloak - +10 Discipline

Quiver - +10 Discipline

1h Xbow - +10 Discipline

We can have a total of +70 Max Discipline, resulting in 100 Discipline with the 30 innate.

Comment: Is there any site that I can search on specific skill on items?

Comment: 88 Max discipline is incredible. That's 13 times SS _without taking regeneration into account_

Comment: @DanielMagnusson Just researched on it via AH and the D3 Game Guide

Comment: @fjdumont That's only 58, not 88 max discipline

Comment: Thats 30 base disc +58 bonus disc, resulting in 88 max disc. I had to check that as well because my DH has 58 max disc without having any on its rings, belt, gloves, or amulet.

Comment: Seems like I can't edit this comment any more, sorry for douplepost... There is a great resource for item affixes (excluding legendaries or set items):
http://diablo.incgamers.com/blog/comments/item-affix-quick-look-chart

Comment: Yeah forgot the innate 30